# R: How can I efficiently generate R formulas for quadratic forms in many variables?

Tags: r, formula, linear-regression, metaprogramming, quadratic

I have asked a couple of versions of this question before, but I am trying again because I am completely convinced that there must be a better answer already out there than I have seen so far.

I am trying to build a bunch of time series models in R that I expect to estimate using a variety of procedures and packages. Each model has three to ten variables initially, but I also want to estimate each as a quadratic form response surface with squared terms and cross-products, a number of lags of each term.

So, for example, suppose I have six variables: `up, down, charm, strange, top`, and `bottom`.

Then I will estimate each variable as the sum of lags of each, plus lags of the square of each, plus lags of the fifteen second-order cross-product terms. And let’s say that I will estimate this particular equation using the package dynlm, to make it easier to vary the number of lags and to take multiple lags, like so:

```
as.formula(up ~ 
lag(up, 1:4) + lag(down, 1:4) + lag(charm, 1:4) + lag(strange, 1:4) + lag(top, 1:4) + lag(bottom, 1:4)) +
```

plus 6 square terms

```
lag(I(up^2), 1:4) + lag(I(down^2), 1:4) + lag(I(charm^2), 1:4) + lag(I(strange^2), 1:4) + lag(I(top^2), 1:4) + lag(I(bottom^2), 1:4)) +
```

plus 15 cross-product terms

```
lag(up_down, 1:4) + lag(up_charm, 1:4) + lag(up_strange, 1:4) + lag(up_top, 1:4) + lag(up_bottom, 1:4) +
lag(down_charm, 1:4) + lag(down_strange, 1:4) + lag(down_top, 1:4) + lag(down_bottom, 1:4) +
lag(charm_strange, 1:4) + lag(charm_top, 1:4) + lag(charm_bottom, 1:4) +
lag(strange_top, 1:4) + lag(strange_bottom, 1:4) +
lag(top_bottom, 1:4))
```

I'm not sure reproducibility is actually useful here, but here is stuff to make the formula above usable as such:

```
set.seed(1)
MX <- matrix(runif(1254), ncol = 6)
colnames(MX)<- c("up", "down", "charm", "strange", "top", "bottom")
library(dynlm)
MX <- mutate(MX,up_down        <- up * down, 
             up_charm       <- up * charm,
             up_strange     <- up * strange,
             up_top         <- up * top,
             up_bottom      <- up * bottom,
             down_charm     <- down * charm,
             down_strange   <- down * strange,
             down_top       <- down * top,
             down_bottom    <- down * bottom,
             charm_strange  <- charm * strange,
             charm_top      <- charm * top,
             charm_bottom   <- charm * bottom,
             strange_top    <- strange * top,
             strange_bottom <- strange * bottom,
             top_bottom     <- top * bottom)
```

I can not use formula multiplication notation to get the interaction terms, both because it drops the squared terms and because (so far as I know) there is no way to do that correctly with lags. Note that I do not want interaction terms between variables with different lags, e.g., I don’t want a term  for `lag(up, 1) * lag(down, 4)`.

So, I have not provided something broken that needs to be fixed. This works. It just feels really stupid to me. Individually typing out these 27 terms, and having to define all but my original six variables with one equation per variable, seems like just the sort of repetitive, error-prone drudgery that R is supposed to let me avoid.

Moreover, my true situation is considerably worse than this, because I want to estimate most of these equations in multiple ways not available through dynlm, so I will not usually have available the extended lag and difference functions that dynlm provides, as used in the example above. In particular I am hoping to use the tools in the new fable/fabletools/tsibble suite, and to run LASSO versions of these formulae, and the like, so instead of 27 terms in the example above, I would have a separate term for each lag level, or 208 terms in all (209 with a constant).

People use R on vastly larger sets of variables than I have here, and I am certain that estimating quadratic forms in those variables has got to be a common problem (like the translog production function from economics, for instance, or quadratic response surface estimation in factorial and fractional factorial designs from many disciplines). Somebody must have figured out a smarter approach than this. Can anyone suggest one?

Comment: `poly(..., raw=TRUE)`? Type `?poly`.